# Formula to array all columns with first column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, unpivot, custom-function

I am pulling in csv data into a Google Spreadsheet which has names running vertically in column A and questions running horizontally in row 1. There are scores in some of the columns and others are blank. Like Such:

```
 |       | Q1  | Q2  | Q3 | Q4  | Q5  | Q6 | Q7  |
 |-------|-----|-----|----|-----|-----|----|-----|
 | Name1 | ##% | ##% |    | ##% | ##% |    | ##% |
 | Name2 | ##% | ##% |    | ##% | ##% |    | ##% |
 | Name3 | ##% | ##% |    | ##% | ##% |    | ##% |
 | Name4 | ##% | ##% |    | ##% | ##% |    |     |
 | Name5 | ##% | ##% |    | ##% | ##% |    |     |
```

I would like to build a formula to match up each columns scores with the names column and the column header into just 3 columns regardless of weather there are any values in the cells. I would Like a names column, a question title column, and a score column like the following:

```
 | Name1 | Q1 | ##% |
 | Name2 | Q1 | ##% |
 | Name3 | Q1 | ##% |
 | Name4 | Q1 | ##% |
 | Name5 | Q1 | ##% |
 | Name1 | Q2 | ##% |
 | Name2 | Q2 | ##% |
 | Name3 | Q2 | ##% |
 | Name4 | Q2 | ##% |
 | Name5 | Q2 | ##% |
 | Name1 | Q3 | ##% |
 | Name2 | Q3 |     |
 | Name3 | Q3 |     |
 | Name4 | Q3 |     |
 | Name5 | Q3 |     |
 And so on....
```

Currently I am doing this by in cell A1 of a new sheet arraying the first column over and over like:

`=   {FILTER(Input!A:A,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!A:A,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!A:A,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!A:A,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!A:A,Input!A:A<>"");
FILTER(Input!A:A,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!A:A,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!A:A,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!A:A,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!A:A,Input!A:A<>"")};`

and then arraying all the columns like this in Cell B2:
`={FILTER(Input!B:B,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!C:C,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!D:D,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!E:E,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!F:F,Input!A:A<>"");
FILTER(Input!G:G,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!H:H,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!I:I,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!J:J,Input!A:A<>"");FILTER(Input!K:K,Input!A:A<>"");}`

I have a formula I have dragged down column C to find the header rows in the array and copy them down for all the names.

Since I have hundreds of columns of questions, these array formulas are huge. Is there a simpler way to do this by simply referencing all the columns with some kind of matrix?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you maybe share an example spreadsheet so that we have some data to work with?

Comment: You may want to look into making a custom script for this using google apps script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a sample script for this kind of tasks. It may be used as custom formula:

`=unpivotTable(false, B1, B2, B3)`

where

1. `false`  to use current file
2. `B1`     holds first header range: `Sheet1!A1`
3. `B2`     holds second header range: `Sheet1!B1:Z1`
4. `B3`     holds headers for pivoted columns: `Question,%`

Plese try if my script fits you:

[Sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fVJnq8RDrX6663M3Xod143rm6cPFH_ahmL3QHXenxxY/edit#gid=2013948078) to explore.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This answer is (IMHO) useless here. You could have shown the code to allow others to learn from.